# How to convert EDAMTimestamp to NSDate with Evernote Cloud SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, evernote

I tried Evernote Cloud SDK 2.0.6 for iOS. When I fetch the EDAMSyncChunk and the note data from Evernote service, created (and also updated and deleted) property as NSNumber type in EDAMNote instance has following values for example:

- 1350039844000
- 765020000

The former seems to be the UNIX time with milliseconds, so I can convert the value to NSDate object, getting "2012-10-12 20:04:04" (JST).

The latter, however, does not seem to be the correct UNIX time because the value cannot be converted to the acceptable time regardless of removing the last three digits:

- 765020000 ---> "1994-03-30 18:33:20" (JST)
- 765020    ---> "1970-01-10 05:30:20" (JST)

How can I get the correct time from the latter case? (I doubt that "765020000" results from something like "xxxx765020000" in 32bit environment, though I cannot check the environment now... sorry)

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, but you can sum them. And you get a different date. I don't know what it means (last update date?), but in your case example, it give what seems to be a valid date.

Comment: Thank you for comment. In the case "765020000", the real note data was created in several years, so the "created" property seems to be like the former case (1350039844000). But I got "765020000" and the converted time "1994-03-30 18:33:20" (JST) is apparently incorrect.

Comment: `(1350039844000)  => 2012-10-12T11:04:04+00:00` (Creation date) and `(1350039844000 + 765020000) => 2012-10-21T07:34:24+00:00` (Upload or last update date)? That's just guess, I don't use Evernote and I'm unfamiliar with you case and the SDK.

Comment: Sorry, "1350039844000" was derived from the "created" property of note A, and  "765020000" from note B, so I think this property can miss the current creation date in some cases such as "765020000". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on my project, I got it working like this (in swift):

```
let date = NSDate(EDAMTimestamp: note.created.longLongValue)
```